# Calculating the volume of multiple lakes with ArcGIS (3D Analyst)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, hydrology

I have the DEM of a glacier bed and want to calculate the volume of bed depressions that could form lakes. Data is available here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT

I've clipped the bedrock under the glacier to the extent of the depressions:

[image]

I understand that it should be possible to use the 3D Analyst to calculate the volume of a single depression, but is it possible to do this with more than one?

Could the solution be to region group the raster and then somehow let ArcMap loop through the regions, taking the respective max_height and calculating the volume below? But I don't know how to do this...

Comment: For the start project your raster from geographic system to something useful, when computing volumes and areas. And perhaps read again my comment to your previous post.